# Group by not working. Cannot not add more than one document per group

Tags: document, library, grouping

I have a document library with a column that I use in the group by. It has only 2 values in the column. After I have created the grouping and I start to upload documents i can only add one document per group. It checks it out to me and after I have filled in the required fields and try to check it in, sharepoint informs me that the value already exists in the list.

I'm confused. Why isn't it letting me check in more than one document per group?

Comment: Did you accidnetly enable "enforce uniqueness" for the column?

Comment: Thank you that worked! I couldn't remember that had an impact on the grouping

Comment: No problem. We always do that.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidently enabled "Enforce Uniqueness" for the column.

Reference: [Enforcing Uniqueness in Column Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536168(v=office.14).aspx)